# "already defined" error while adding cpp to solution explorer

Tags: visual-c++

I have dll project that includes additionally `A.h` header file. `A.cpp` includes A.h and B.cpp that has o header. If I do add `B.cpp` to visual c++ project compiler reports many errors :

```
Error   9   error LNK2005: "wchar_t * __stdcall aaa(int)" (?aaa@@YGPA_WH@Z) already defined in A.obj    C:\P\B.obj  pr1
```

There are no problems and project compiles fine in case if I leave `B.cpp` in project directory, but not add it to project.

That is the problem with adding `B.cpp` file?

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild?

Comment: `A.cpp` should not include `B.cpp` but only headerfiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include` is for header files, not other .cpp files.

Remove `#include "B.cpp"` from A.cpp, and things will start behaving properly.

Or rename B.cpp to B.h if you intend to include it.

Comment: I thought that extensions has no influence and might be whatever you want. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I can rename B.h to B.fss , define this in source and compiler should compile.

Comment: Extensions don't mean anything to the compiler.  They do have meaning to the IDE, however.  Files added to the project and named `.cpp` will trigger the compiler running and being passed that filename.  Files added to the project named `.h` will not cause the compiler to run again, because the IDE assumes the compiler will read those when it sees `#include` directives.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that extensions has no influence and might be whatever you want. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I can rename B.h to B.fss , define this in source and compiler should compile

Your b.cpp will be automatically compiled if you include it in the project; and as you are including contents of the same file elsewhere as well, the code in it will be compiled again, resulting in duplicate definition errors

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you include something that has definitions instead of declarations in one .cpp file and also add it to the project of course you will get multiple definition errors - move the definitions for the stuff in B.cpp to B.h and include that in A.cpp. The issue is not file extensions, the issue is that you need to understand that multiple definitions of the same thing will lead to such errors.